# Blender model deforms too much in unreal

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-weights, distort

Alright so I created a mesh in blender (okay, i threw some crappy sculpt onto the UE manni, and drew over it)

I keep getting 2 problems.
Finger tips just go where ever they want.... Seems weird as they are weighted exactly to that section... And my character pulls his back through himself.

On these photos the left shoulder is set to ONLY be weighted to shoulder. And the right fades out into 1/2 across back. Results arent very different.
I also tried weighting back to the spine_03 that is right there but that REALLY pulled it making it pass the neck and everything.

Can anyone give some insight on how to straighten that out?
[image]

My FBX i made in blender is here: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-V...wbODXgvo79ds9h

Answer (score 0):

Going in and setting all the weights to a much smoother rate of change, and removing some from the auto weight option cleaned this up.

[image]